# Recovery Partition in Windows 8 hogging space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, data-recovery

Ok, I am trying Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I have used Ubuntu briefly when I had Win7 but that was many many years ago, and went by a lot easier.

The issue I'm having is that Windows 8.1 has a recovery partition that is hogging 9GB of my hard drive. This has caused  me to not have any space to do almost anything in Ubuntu. Can I safely remove Recovery? If I do remove it can the space freed be used for Ubuntu? Does simply deleting apps and files from Windows 8.1 matter for space in Ubuntu?

I also want to add that Ubuntu is installed and working, however any Ubuntu apps won't install and Ubuntu won't update due to lack of memory.

Comment: How much space did you give Ubuntu? Even 10 GB should be enough to install common apps and upgrade things.

Comment: I only had 7 GB. But I found something to help free space up to 50 GB

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows 7 era, pre-installed versions of Windows typically came with programs to create a set of recovery DVDs. These could then take the place of the recovery partition. I don't know offhand if Windows 8 installations come with similar tools. (I'd expect them to use USB flash drives today.) You could look for such a thing. If it exists, use it, and it will then be (relatively) safe to remove the recovery partition.

In Linux, partitions are mounted to particular directories. For instance, your main Windows partition might be mounted to `/windows`. In this scheme, deleting files in Windows will make space available in Ubuntu, but only under `/windows`. You don't normally install programs there, but you might be able to use that space for storing user files. Also, there's a caveat: For native Linux use, NTFS is slow and lacks features that Linux requires for some purposes. Furthermore, Linux includes no good NTFS recovery tools (`ntfsfix` does only the most basic checks and flags the partition as needing attention in Windows). Thus, if you want to use space exclusively in Linux, or for tasks such as holding additional Linux programs, you've got to resize your partitions, shrinking the Windows partition(s) and giving space to the Linux partition(s). You'll probably have to use a Linux live CD/USB for this task, since GParted won't let you resize a partition that's in use.

Also, if you delete the Windows recovery partition, its space will be unusable unless and until you resize partition(s) to fill its space, or create a new partition in its place.

Finally, note that resizing partitions is inherently dangerous. This is especially true if you change the start point of a partition. You should back up any important data from a partition before you attempt to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise great caution here. I've just been through the same excercise trying to improve my free space on a Acer E11, which only has a 32Gb SSD built in to it. There was just 18Gb of disk allocated to Windows, and there was 10Gb recovery partition.

The OS identified itself as Windows 8.1 with bing. The 'bing' is actually a code for a sub-version of windows that makes use of some of the recovery files during boot, and as such it cannot be removed. Added to that the recovery partition is locked, so you can't re-size it with any tools, unless you can do it outside of windows, and with UEFI thats quite a task.

Assuming you've got an OEM built system, then there will be lots of 'free' goodies from the manuafacturer, and one of them will most likely have a button that allows you to create a recovery backup. On my machine the backup needed to be done to a device connected to the USB port with at least 16Gb of space. I know, the recovery partition is only 10Gb!! But I think they were thinking of USB memory sticks, which these days come in powers of 2 sizes (4Gb, 8Gb, 16Gb etc).

I tried installing from a windows 8.1 install disk, which worked, but actually ended up using up more space. I also tried installing windows 7, but as my machine has USB3.0 ports and no optical drive, it lost its connection to the USB external DVD drive as soon as it go into the setting up windows section.

In the end the only way to save space was good old-fashioned housekeeping. Delecte unwanted programs (mine had a 360Mb copy of Office 365 the you could activate by buying a susbscription), carefully decide which, if any of the manufacturers free gifts you are ever going to use, then get rid of the rest. Uninstall windows features that you don't use. Disable hibernation if you don't use it (this is a massive saving - it takes up as much room as you have RAM). Finally run disc cleanup and select "clean-up system files", this allows you to delete the backup copies of files that windows update has replaced.

I started with just 6Gb free, and after housekeeping, I've got just 6Gb used, 13Gb free (thats less than half the size of when I started).

Answer (score 0):

If your trouble is to save space, you can use [bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org) on windows **and** linux. It will removes the caches of a lot of apps, the history and a lot of stuff. You should be really carefull about options you choose, because some features are in beta and could definitely crash your computer. But if you do it carefully, you can save **a lot** of space.

On windows only, you can use [ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com), which further than remove the caches, can also detects copies of files. (On the same link, defraggler is also usefull to better organize your memory, which is healthy for the pc, but it's another subject)